# Broken Image displaying in Table Cell whereas Image is shown perfectly outside the table

Tags: jquery, html, image, model-view-controller

I am having trouble loading image file in the table cell using jquery.
My View has following code:

```
<table id="personDataTable" border="1">
        <tr style="font-size:large; height:auto">
            <th width="100">First Name</th>
            <th width="100">Last Name</th>
            <th width="100">Address</th>
            <th width="100">Age</th>
            <th width="500">Photo</th>
       </tr>
    </table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnGetPersons').click(function () {
            var searchKey = $("#txtBoxPersonSearch").val();
            $.getJSON("/Person/GetJsonData", { search: searchKey }, function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    drawRow(data[i]);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    function drawRow(rowData) {
        debugger;
        var row = $("<tr/>")
        var img = "<img src=" + "~/Images/" + rowData.Photo + "/>";
        $("#personDataTable").append(row);
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.FirstName + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.LastName + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.Address + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.Age + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + img + "</td>"));
    }
```

While I debugged the script the Image path that I get in img, is correct. Also when I add individual img element with the same source as follows, it is displayed perfectly.

```
  <div> <img src="~/Images/C__Image1.jpg" /></div>
```

However, its not displayed inside the table cell.

Please let me know where I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> You have applied width on th tag within table tag:

```
<th width="500">Photo</th>
```

Due to this it's not showing full images. And images are broken. Remove width from th tag.

```
<th>Photo</th>
```

Comment: I think you have applied width outside the table... perhaps on id, body or any other tag

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine to me if I modify it a bit to use local data:

```
function drawRow(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr/>")
    var img = "<img src='https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=100%C3%97100&w=100&h=100'/>";
    $("#personDataTable").append(row);
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.FirstName + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.LastName + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.Address + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.Age + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + img + "</td>"));
}

drawRow({FirstName: "john", LastName: "Doe", Address: "123", Age: "69"});
```

JSFiddle of it working: https://jsfiddle.net/05qe1ggo/1/

---

One thing I noticed is that your code that generates the image url doesn't add the required quotes within the tag. Try changing

```
"<img src=" + "~/Images/" + rowData.Photo + "/>";
```

to

```
"<img src=\"" + "~/Images/" + rowData.Photo + "\" />";
```

Comment: Yes, the static image works. But it does not work for the image path that comes from rowdata. Also I tried updating the image url as you said, but that isn't working either.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that you are using a tilda (~) in your file path. Tildas aren't standard in web urls, so I would change it to be a relative url instead, like this: `"<img src=\"" + "Images/" + rowData.Photo + "\" />";`. This will look for the image in the "Images" folder in the same folder as the html file.

Comment: I tried with the updated string as well. But its still showing broken image.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working with my local image.

According to me the problem is here

`var img = "<img src=" + "~/Images/" + rowData.Photo + "/>";`

Ensure `rowData.Photo` is giving you the correct image, alert variable `img` after the above code and see whether you are getting the intended image path properly.

Comment: I double-checked the value from rowData.Photo. It is just the image name with extension like testImage.png. the img variable has following value in it. <img src=~/Images/testImage.png />                                                                     When I try this string with normal img tag, the image is displayed well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with giving a space at the end of closing image tag?

```
var img = "<img src=" + "~/Images/" + rowData.Photo + " />";
```

I believe without a space it is generating image tag like:

```
<img src="~/Images/abc.png/">
```

Comment: Ok. Just to make sure it isn't absolute/relative path related issue in image tag, can you try giving exact image url i.e. http://localhost/images/ +  rowData.Photo